# ftp_nlist ... how to know if it's a file or a folder?

Tags: php, ftp

I'm writing a script for download from FTP..
In the form I need to show files and folders..
With ftp_nlist, they come all togethers but I want to know who's who ..
I can't find an easy way to do this:

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($connection, $rep);
$dossiers =array();
$fichiers = array();
foreach($contents as $content){
    //if folder
    if (is_folder($content)) $dossiers[] = $content;
    //si file
    if(is_filex($content)) $fichiers[] = $content;
}
```

Of course is_file and is_dir don't work with distant files...

I've find something with ftp_rawlist and the size of each result..
like this:

```
  if($result['size']== 0){ //is dir }
```

But in case of an empty file???

So what id the way to know what is a folder and what is a file?? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and this was my solution:

```
$conn = ftp_connect('my_ftp_host');
ftp_login($conn,  'my_user', 'my_password');

$path       = '/';

// Get lists
$nlist  = ftp_nlist($conn, $path);
$rawlist    = ftp_rawlist($conn, $path);

$ftp_dirs   = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($nlist) - 1; $i++) 
{ 
    if($rawlist[$i][0] == 'd')
    {
        $ftp_dirs[] = $nlist[$i];
    }
}
```

I know the above code could be optimised and do just one FTP request instead of two but for my purposes this did the work.

For anyone looking for a cleaner solution, I've found a script to parse `ftp_rawlist` in this [LINK](https://andreas.glaser.me/2009/03/12/php-ftp_rawlist-parser-windows-unixlinux/):

**Function**

```
function parse_ftp_rawlist($List, $Win = FALSE)
{
  $Output = array();
  $i = 0;
  if ($Win) {
    foreach ($List as $Current) {
      ereg('([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) +([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(AM|PM) +([0-9]+|) +(.+)', $Current, $Split);
      if (is_array($Split)) {
        if ($Split[3] < 70) {
          $Split[3] += 2000;
        }
        else {
          $Split[3] += 1900;
        }
        $Output[$i]['isdir']     = ($Split[7] == '');
        $Output[$i]['size']      = $Split[7];
        $Output[$i]['month']     = $Split[1];
        $Output[$i]['day']       = $Split[2];
        $Output[$i]['time/year'] = $Split[3];
        $Output[$i]['name']      = $Split[8];
        $i++;
      }
    }
    return !empty($Output) ? $Output : false;
  }
  else {
    foreach ($List as $Current) {
      $Split = preg_split('[ ]', $Current, 9, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
      if ($Split[0] != 'total') {
        $Output[$i]['isdir']     = ($Split[0] {0} === 'd');
        $Output[$i]['perms']     = $Split[0];
        $Output[$i]['number']    = $Split[1];
        $Output[$i]['owner']     = $Split[2];
        $Output[$i]['group']     = $Split[3];
        $Output[$i]['size']      = $Split[4];
        $Output[$i]['month']     = $Split[5];
        $Output[$i]['day']       = $Split[6];
        $Output[$i]['time/year'] = $Split[7];
        $Output[$i]['name']      = $Split[8];
        $i++;
      }
    }
    return !empty($Output) ? $Output : FALSE;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
// connect to ftp server
$res_ftp_stream = ftp_connect('my_server_ip');

// login with username/password
$login_result = ftp_login($res_ftp_stream, 'my_user_name', 'my_password');

// get the file list for curent directory
$buff = ftp_rawlist($res_ftp_stream, '/');

// parse ftp_rawlist output
$result = parse_ftp_rawlist($buff, false);

// dump result
var_dump($result);

// close ftp connection
ftp_close($res_ftp_stream);
```